# Python: how do I create a dict of lists containing the euclidean distances from a point?

Tags: python, dictionary, euclidean-distance

Say that I have a regular grid of points with a given set of coordinates, like this:

```
Node IDs            Coordinates
0   1   2           (0,0)  (1,0)  (2,0)
3   4   5           (0,1)  (1,1)  (2,1)
6   7   8           (0,2)  (1,2)  (2,2)
```

In my case, the regular grid is a `2D graph` generated with NetworkX.

How can I create a `dict` of lists where the key represents each node ID in the network and the list contains the distances from one specific node to those that are connected to it?

**Example:** node `(0,0)` is connected to nodes `(1,0)` and `(0,1)`. Considering the squared distance to avoid the computational costs of `sqrt`, the dict I want would feature `mydict={0:[1,1],...]`, since the squared distance from node `(0,0)` to its connected neighbors is in both cases 1. Each list is therefore as long as there are neighbors to the each node.

I failed to provide some code as I don't understand how to solve the problem. Many thanks to those who will help.

**EDIT**

This is how the regular network is created:

```
import networkx as nx
N=3
G=nx.grid_2d_graph(N,N)
pos = dict( (n, n) for n in G.nodes() )
labels = dict( ((i, j), i + (N-1-j) * N ) for i, j in G.nodes() )
nx.relabel_nodes(G,labels,False)
inds=labels.keys()
vals=labels.values()
inds.sort()
vals.sort()
pos2=dict(zip(vals,inds))
nx.draw_networkx(G, pos=pos2, with_labels=False, node_size = 15)
```

This is how one can get the neighbors of each node:

```
for node in G.nodes():
        list_of_neigh=G.neighbors(node) #The connected neighbors of node n
```

And this is how one can access each node in the graph:

```
G.nodes()
```

Comment: You need to provide a little bit of surrounding code. How is your data stored in the python program? Are nodes just tuples or are they instances of a custom class? How can we access the neighbors given a node?

Comment: If you're running around bulding dynamically allocated 2-item lists stuffed into a dictionary in Python, I think the additional cost of a square root is neglible. :)

Comment: Even if the number of lists is `900`?

Comment: @FC84 `sum(math.sqrt(n) for n in range(1000000))` takes less than a second to evaluate, so, yes, the cost is somewhat neglible.

Comment: Ok, let's use the `sqrt` then. But this is not the reason why I asked this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing that nodes are tuples (a,b), something like this (not tested)? :

```
def dist(n1, n2):
    x = n2[0]-n1[0]
    y = n2[1]-n1[1]
    return math.sqrt(x*x + y*y)   # or math.hypot(x, y)

distances = {}
for node in G.nodes():
    list_of_neigh = G.neighbors(node)
    distances[node] = [dist(node, x) for x in list_of_neigh]
```

Comment: I get a `TypeError: 'int' object has no attribute '__getitem__' ` pointing at `x=n2[0]-n1[0]`. What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that I assumed that your nodes were tuples of ints, whereas apparently they are only ints (cannot use `[]` on an int, probably `n2` is an int). Make it so that `node`, `x`, `n1`, `n2` are all couples of coordinates like you described.

Comment: Well I don't know how to do that :)

Comment: What does `node` look like ? Can you print it ? It may be an object `Node`, and you access its properties like `node.x`, `node.y` instead of `node[0]`, `node[1]`.

Comment: If you type `G.nodes()` that'll give you a `list`, so the nodes are the elements of that list. The properties you might be referring to are the coordinates, which are stored in the `pos2` dict.

Comment: So I have amended your `x = n2[0]-n1[0]` line to be `x = pos2[n1][0]-pos2[n2][0]` since `pos2` stores the coordinates. Similarly I have amended the `y` line.

Comment: Yes, that should work. What is `G.nodes()[0]` ? I doubt you have to use your own dict for that.